# Jquery blockUI problem on onclick

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have this code in my js file

```
function blockUI() {
    $.blockUI({ css: {
        border: 'none',
        padding: '15px',
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
        '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
        opacity: .5,
        color: '#fff'
    }
    });
    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
}
```

when I am trying to block the UI on Submit button click I am doing soemthing like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="javascript:blockUI();" class="t-grid-action t-button t-state-default" />
```

but on my oncick its not working for me? can any one tell me what is the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your js file is properly referenced from your html file. Can you call other js functions from here? You can also use Firebug to see if the js file has been loaded. If so, set a breakpoint in your function to make sure it's been executed.

As ob mentioned, you may want to return false, depending on what you want your submit button to do after blockUI() is called, but you should return false after your function call, not during the function body.

Lastly, why are you calling this inline? jQuery was designed for UJS. You should have script tags in your html file that contain some jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submit').click(function() {
    blockUI();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to add `return false;` at the end of your function to prevent your form from posting

Comment: thanks ob, buts its not going to BlockUI function at all. bec I tried keeping alert box on the blockUi funcation.. I am not able to see that alret box.